# Need result set of sql Query in the order gave as input in "in" function without any creation and insertions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-in

Need the result set of the SQL query in the order of the param values what i gave in the in function order.

```
mysql> select * from state where state_name in ("UP","AP","Orissa","MP");

+------------+
| state_name |
+------------+
| AP         |
| MP         |
| UP         |
| Orissa     |
+------------+
```

4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Please suggest a solution that can help without using any extra insertions and creations.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from state where state_name in ("UP","AP","Orissa","MP")    
order by FIELD(state_name ,"UP","AP","Orissa","MP")
```

Answer (score 0):

With ANSI sql CASE

```
select * from state where state_name in ("UP","AP","Orissa","MP")
order by case state_name 
         when "UP" then 1 
         when "AP" then 2 
         when "Orissa" then 3 
         when "MP" then 4 
         else 5 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school:

```
SELECT
  State.*
FROM State
JOIN (SELECT 'UP' sn, '1' pos UNION ALL
      SELECT 'AP', '2' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Orissa', '3' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'MP', '4') SortOrder
ON State.state_name = SortOrder.sn
ORDER BY SortOrder.pos;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5b86c/3/0)